# Do I need postfix service running while sending email using SMTP details of other email server?

Tags: smtp, sendmail, phpmailer

I am trying to send email using PHPMailer class with SMTP details,
My email server is hosted on other server. In this case do need postfix or sendmail service on web server to send emails though my email server is different?

e.g.

My domain is abc.com and my email is hosted on other server as abcmail.com and I am using SMTP authentication details of abcmail.com to send emails on abc.com by using PHPMail class.

But when I stop postfix service on abc.com mails stops working and when I restart postfix mails gets started again?

So is it mandatory to have postfix / sendmail service running on webserver to send emails though I use SMTP authentication details of some other email server?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you're sending via a remote SMTP host, you don't need a local mail server.

This is one of the reasons for PHPMailer's popularity - it's very common for Windows servers (unlike Linux servers) not to have a local mail server configured by default, so you need to be able to send to remote SMTP hosts directly, which isn't possible with a stock PHP config, so you need something like PHPMailer.

It sounds like you have a broken config, so I suggest you enable `SMTPDebug = 2` so you can see what's going on in the SMTP conversation - e.g. to confirm that it's connecting to the correct server.

Comment: Hello Synchro, Thank you very much for your quick response. I will try setting SMTPDebug to 2 and check whats happening actually. Again thanks for quick response.

Comment: Hi @Synchro

   I tried sending email by using this method and setting debugmode to 2. At my end $mail->Send() is succeeding and showing no error. but actually mail is not going to the destined user. Could you please help me how can I debug it further?

Comment: If your message is being delivered successfully to your mail server, then that's where PHPMailer's involvement ends. Beyond that you will need to look at your mail server's logs to find out what happens after that.

Comment: Hi Synchro, Mail is not going to smtp mail server I am seeing those in mailq when I try using "mailq" command and when I again start postfix "service" mails are getting sent. Does it mean that I either need "sendmail" or "postfix" one of these service running to forward emails to other smtp server?

Comment: Of course it does. Your mail server is not going to send anything if it's not running.